# Creating a gradle based android project via command line

Tags: android, gradle

I need to use a low end machine for android dev. I successfully created a test project using the command line:

```
   android create project --target <target-id> --name MyFirstApp \
   --path <path-to-workspace>/MyFirstApp --activity MyActivity \
   --package com.example.myfirstapp
```

However I see that it does not create any gradle files and the structure seems different that when I create a project in Studio. How do I create a project from the command line so that it includes the build.gradle files as well? Currently I do see a build.xml file that must be ant but I haven't used ant before.

Comment: I would just copy some example/mini project and adapt the build.gradle

Comment: Why not to create the gradle file via any text editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-g` option when creating the project. For more details, try

`android create project -h`